# How to autofill forms by browser autocomplete attributes without any click?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, autocomplete, autofill

is there any way to autofill fields by browser autofill feature with no user click.

can be done with any javascript code which provide autoclick or something different?

i dont want to grap data but i only want to prove a solution that autofill input labels when page loading and no need to user action. after that users can can change everthing and submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this.  It would be a huge security risk to allow a method for a new website to grab credentials automatically as they could then be sent to the server.

Depending on the browser, with the correct field names, the browser may autofill the fields for your particular site if they have visited before, but with multiple possibilities they will not pick one.